# javascript errors after migrating wordpress site to live server (ISS 8.5 )

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, migration

I migrated to the live server. This is running ISS v8.5. Now i have multiple problems that are related to js files. Which weren't there in the testing environment.

Since i copied the wordpress 4.8 website and fixed all the files and linkings i noticed the following problems:

- visual composer backend editor wont show, and clicking the backend editor button does nothing. (javascript function). Front-end live editor is working.
- in the frontend my (woocommerce) productpage is showing product-pictures in a new page instead of replacing the main/featured product-picture. (slideshow javascript function)
- The datepicker addon for contact form 7 is not working either. It just shows a input field but on click a date-selector will not appear.

Most of the js is working great though. And all of it was working great in my linux testing environment. Am i missing something here?? I think its related due to the server settings (ISS 8.5 php 5.5)

**Problems in inspector:**

```
jquery.flexslider-min.js?ver=5.2:6 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

photoswipe.min.js?ver=4.1.1:4 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

jquery-ui-timepicker-nl.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'regional' of undefined

www.dab-scooters.nl/:639 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function
```

Comment: backend is showing a Typeerror on the visual composer js and syntaxerror on the backend.min.js. All new since migrating the site, all assumably good code